# Is jdbcType necessary in a MyBatis mapper?

Tags: jdbc, mybatis

I've been searching and I don't have this very clear. When using a MyBatis mapper, is it necessary to set the `jdbcType`? I'm using it with MySql.

For what I've read, it's for when you pass null values, but I don't know if this is still necessary or it's something old. For example, both of these queries work:

```
SELECT <include refid="columns"/> FROM user WHERE uid=#{uid, jdbcType=INTEGER}

SELECT <include refid="columns"/> FROM user WHERE uid=#{uid}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As you mentioned yourself, you need to specify the `jdbcType` when passing null values for parameters.

Some databases need to know the value's type even if the value itself is NULL. For this reason, **for maximum portability**, it's the [JDBC specification itself that requires the type](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setNull%28int,%20int%29) to be specified and MyBatis needs to pass it along since it's build on top of JDBC.

From the [MyBatis documentation](http://mybatis.github.io/mybatis-3/sqlmap-xml.html#id__result):

> The JDBC type is only required for nullable columns upon insert, update or delete. This
>   is a JDBC requirement, not a MyBatis one. So even if you were coding JDBC directly, you'd need to specify this type – but only for nullable values.

Most of the times you don't need to specify the `jdbcType` as MyBatis is smart enough to figure out the type from the objects you are working with. But if you send your parameters to the MyBatis statement inside a `HashMap`, for example, and one of the parameters is null, MyBatis won't be able to determine the type of the parameter by looking at the `HashMap` because the `HashMap` is just a generic container and `null` itself carries no type information. At that point it would be o good idea to provide the `jdbcType` so that switching the database implementation later on does not cause any issues with null values.

Comment: So apparently the db @enkara was using was a type of db that doesn't "need to know the value's type even if the value itself is NULL".  I have the same experience they do, with everything working while not specifying jdbcType.