# In MyBatis, is there any solution for not adding jdbcType when setting null parameters?

Tags: java, sql, mybatis

I'm using mybatis-3.2.8.jar and JDK 1.6.0_45.

The source table is called `emp`:

```
> EMPNO ENAME   JOB         MGR     HIREDATE            SAL     COMM  DEPTNO  SHORTCUT
> 
> 7499  ALLEN   SALESMAN    7698    1981/02/20 00:00:00 1600    300   30 null
```

and the SQL is this:

```
insert into emp (EMPNO, ENAME, JOB, MGR, HIREDATE, SAL, COMM, DEPTNO, SHORTCUT)
values
(#{EMPNO},#{ENAME},#{JOB},#{MGR},#{HIREDATE},#{SAL},#{COMM},#{DEPTNO},#{SHORTCUT});
```

I'm using this SQL row by row. Select 1 row then insert, again and again. Or think the table just has 1 row.

Then I'm facing this error:

```
org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.PersistenceException: 
#### Error updating database.  Cause: org.apache.ibatis.type.TypeException: Error setting null for parameter #7 with JdbcType OTHER . Try setting a different JdbcType for this parameter or a different jdbcTypeForNull configuration property. Cause: com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlSyntaxErrorException: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, SQLERRMC=insert into TB_ODS_EMP2(EMPNO,ENAME,JOB,MGR;BEGIN-OF-STATEMENT;<grant>, DRIVER=4.12.55
#### The error may involve pdss5.hs.hdw.ETLTargetMapper.insertTargetTable-Inline
#### The error occurred while setting parameters
#### SQL: insert into TB_ODS_EMP2(EMPNO,ENAME,JOB,MGR,HIREDATE,SAL,COMM,DEPTNO,SHORTCUT) values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?) Call getNextException to see the cause
#### Cause: org.apache.ibatis.type.TypeException: Error setting null for parameter #7 with JdbcType OTHER . Try setting a different JdbcType for this parameter or a different jdbcTypeForNull configuration property. Cause: com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlSyntaxErrorException: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, SQLERRMC=insert into TB_ODS_EMP2(EMPNO,ENAME,JOB,MGR;BEGIN-OF-STATEMENT;<grant>, DRIVER=4.12.55
```

My chief didn't want to use `jdbyTYPE` like this:

```
insert into emp
(#{EMPNO},#{ENAME},#{JOB},#{MGR},#{HIREDATE},#{SAL},#{COMM},#{DEPTNO},`#{SHORTCUT,jdbcTYPE=VARCHAR}`)
 ......
```

In MyBatis, is there any solution for not adding jdbcType when setting null parameters?

I think adding `jdbcTYPE=VARCHAR` is good enough, but my chief hates it (maybe...).

Comment: And it's for oracle to DB2. if Oracle to Oracle, did not meet error. I do not know WHY.    :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some databases don't allow untyped `null` to be sent in the query so you should send it or switching from one database vendor to another might later cause your SQL to fail.

See here for extra explanations: [Is jdbcType necessary in a MyBatis mapper?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18645820/is-jdbctype-necessary-in-a-mybatis-mappe)

The `jdbcType` is not actually a MyBatis requirement but a JDBC one. It's good practice to always send `jdbcType` for `null` parameters.

Answer (score 0):

I give up.

DB2 is super-typed database.

Oracle is ok to non-typed inserting through mybatis. Ofcourse set the jdbdtypeForNull in MyBatis.

But DB2 is NOT.